# Selenium with Power Apps

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection

We have a client requirement to implement a test automation in Power apps.
Power apps has its own Testing framework but that is still in **Experimental** mode and not recommended to use for production environment.

I've experience around Selenium but I'm facing issues while locating web elements for Power Apps.
I'm trying to locate a Text box and enter any value, even though the web elements are unique the selenium is not able to find those.

**HTML**

```
<div class="canvasContentDiv appmagic-control-view appmagic-content- 
control-name _vst_" data-control-id="17" data-control-name="TextInput1" 
style="width: 419px; height: 60px; z-index: 17; position: absolute; top: 
517px; left: 105px;"><div class="appmagic-borderfill-container" 
style="background-color: rgb(186, 202, 226); border-style: solid; border- 
width: 2px; border-color: rgb(0, 18, 107); border-radius: 5px; margin: 
-1px;"><div class="appmagic-border-inner" style="margin: -1px;"><div 
class="react-knockout-control" spellcheck="false" style="position: 
absolute; inset: 0px;"> 
 <div class="appmagic-textbox" touch-action="pan-x pan-y" appmagic- 
control="TextInput1">
<!-- ko if: (mode() === "multiline") --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: (mode() !== "multiline") -->
<input appmagic-control="TextInput1textbox" class="appmagic-text mousetrap 
block-undo-redo" maxlength="10000" data-bind="
  attr: {
    type: mode() === 'password' ? 'password' : 'text',
    title: properties.Tooltip() || null,
    'aria-label': properties.AccessibleLabel() || null,
    placeholder: properties.HintText,
    readonly: viewState.displayMode() === 
    AppMagic.Constants.DisplayMode.View,
    contenteditable: viewState.displayMode() === 
    AppMagic.Constants.DisplayMode.Edit,
    'data-control-part': properties.Clear() ? 'text clearable' : 'text',
    inputmode: keyboardMode
  },
  css: {
    underline: properties.Underline,
    strikethrough: properties.Strikethrough,
    readonly: viewState.displayMode() === 
   AppMagic.Constants.DisplayMode.View
  },
  value: text,
  event: {
    click: handleClick,
    change: handleOnChange
  },
  style: {
    fontFamily: properties.Font,
    fontSize: properties.Size,
    color: autoProperties.Color,
    fontWeight: properties.FontWeight,
    fontStyle: properties.Italic,
    textAlign: properties.Align,
    lineHeight: properties.LineHeight,
    paddingTop: properties.PaddingTop,
    paddingRight: properties.PaddingRight,
    paddingBottom: properties.PaddingBottom,
    paddingLeft: properties.PaddingLeft
  },
  disable: viewState.displayMode() === 
 AppMagic.Constants.DisplayMode.Disabled" type="text" placeholder="Team 
 name..." contenteditable="true" data-control-part="text" inputmode="text" 
 tabindex="15" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font- 
 size: 21pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; 
 text-align: left; line-height: 1.2; padding: 5px 5px 5px 12px;"> 

 <div class="appmagic-text-clear-container">
 <button class="appmagic-text-clear-button" data-control-part="clear" data- 
  bind="
    visible: isFocused() &amp;&amp; properties.Clear() &amp;&amp; 
 properties.Text() &amp;&amp; mode() !== 'password' &amp;&amp; 
 viewState.displayMode() === AppMagic.Constants.DisplayMode.Edit,
    event: {click: handleClearClick},
    attr: {'aria-label': AppMagic.Strings.TextInputClearButtonLabel}" aria- 
 label="Clear value" tabindex="16" style="display: none;">
    <svg class="appmagic-text-clear-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
viewBox="0 0 12 12" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
      <polygon points="12,1.1 10.9,0 6,4.9 1.1,0 0,1.1 4.9,6 0,10.9 1.1,12 
6,7.1 10.9,12 12,10.9 7.1,6" data-bind="style: {fill: 
autoProperties.Color}" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></polygon>
    </svg>
</button>
 </div>
<!-- /ko -->
</div>
</div></div></div></div>
```

**Tried below to find the web element-**

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='appmagic-textbox']")).sendKeys("test");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='appmagic-text mousetrap block-undo-redo']")).sendKeys("Test");

Following is the error returned by Selenium-

[image]
Any help or suggestions around this would be very helpful.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Instead of the handcrafted HTML, update the question with the text based actual HTML

Comment: Please include the error that is returned when you try what you posted above.

Comment: Updated the question with HTML and error description.